Error while renewing certificate with certbot on Debian
While executing certbot renew command suddenly this error occurs:
ImportError: cannot import name 'FILETYPE_PEM' from 'OpenSSL.crypto' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py)
OS: on Debian 12
python: 3.9
certbot: 1.12.0
HTTP service: Nginx
I expect that as usual the certificate be renewed.

I managed to fix it by unsintalling python3-openssl and reinstalling python3-certbot:
sudo apt remove python3-openssl
sudo apt install python3-certbot
sudo certbot renew
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx

